# how to get DIV object reality height in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

please see: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/cGJp4/)

```
$("#stdout").height()
```

return `18px`

I want to get the  reality height ( height + padding + border ) `200px`

how to do?

thank for help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [.outerHeight()](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/)

```
$("#stdout").outerHeight();
// returns ( height + padding + border )
```

And if you want to include margin as well:

```
$("#stdout").outerHeight( true );
// returns ( height + padding + border + margin )
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way:

```
$.fn.getHeight = function()
{
    return ($(this).height() + parseInt($(this).css("padding-top")) + parseInt($(this).css("padding-bottom")) + parseInt($(this).css("borderTopWidth")) + parseInt($(this).css("borderBottomWidth")));
};

$.fn.getWidth = function()
{
    return ($(this).width() + parseInt($(this).css("padding-left")) + parseInt($(this).css("padding-right")) + parseInt($(this).css("borderLeftWidth")) + parseInt($(this).css("borderRightWidth")));
};
```

To use this function, simply call:

```
obj.getHeight()
```

Or:

```
$(this).getHeight();
```